# Automapper ignoring nested property

Tags: c#, properties, automapper

I am trying to ignore nested property inside **InProductionRWDto** class.

```
public class InProductionRWDto
{
    public int InProductionRWId { get; set; }
    public int InProductionId { get; set; }
    public InProductionDto InProduction { get; set; }
    public WareDto Ware { get; set; }
    public int? WareQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? WareLength { get; set; }
    public string WareUnit { get; set; }
    public int ToIssue { get; set; } = 1;
    public int ToIssuePerBook { get; set; } = 1;
    public int ToIssuePerSubOrder { get; set; } = 1;
    public int PlannedToCut { get; set; }
    public int Issued { get; set; }
    public int TotalToIssue { get; set; }
    public decimal? QtyWhDiff { get; set; }
    public sbyte ProductionStateCode { get; set; }
}
```

But when I do that:

```
CreateMap<InProductionRW, InProductionRWDto>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.InProduction.ParentReservation, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Automapper is ignoring entire **InProduction** property.

**UPDATE!**

Maps for **InProduction** class

```
CreateMap<InProduction, InProductionDto>();
CreateMap<InProductionDto, InProduction>();
```

Comment: What object maps to the `InProduction` property? There should be a `CreateMap` between those two objects, and that's where I'd normally put the ignore.

Comment: Yes, I'm mapping the InProduction property - see updated question. But when I ignore ParentReservation in InProduction mapping, AutoMapper rises StackOverflow Exception.

Comment: So it looks like you're going from InProduction to InProductionDto, so use your first example and add the ignore to that one. `CreateMap<InProduction, InProductionDto>().ForMember(source => source.ParentReservation, x => x.Ignore();`  If that works I'll make an answer.

Comment: It is not working. Im getting StackOverflowException: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll

Comment: Which version of C# and automapper are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by deleting navigation properties from all of the DTO's. They were causing circular references which ultimately was leading to StackOverFlow exception.

Comment: Maybe you're on an older version of AM. I don't see how this could possibly happen in newer versions. See [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#circular-references).

Answer (score -1):

!PropInfo.DeclaringType.Name.Equals(PropInfo.PropertyType.Name)